# Syncfusion Angular - Grid checkbox selection how to display in custom ng-template #rowTemplate

Tags: angular, syncfusion

I'm working with Angular Grid for some UI design I've to add the custom row-template.

**Question: How do I add checkbox selection functionality to a custom rowTemplate?**

Normally it'll just be:

```
<ejs-grid [dataSource]='data' height='315px'>
   <e-columns>
     <e-column type='checkbox' width='50'></e-column>
     <e-column field='OrderID' headerText='Order ID' textAlign='Right'></e-column>
            ...
     <e-column field='lastColumn' headerText='Actions' textAlign='Right'></e-column>
   <e-columns>
</ejs-grid>
```

And this will display a checkbox in each of the row. Clicking on the main column would select all the row checkboxes and the entire functionality that it carries.

But in my case this is a summary of my code:

```
<ejs-grid [dataSource]='data'>
   <e-columns>
     <e-column type='checkbox' width='50'></e-column>
     <e-column field='OrderID' headerText='Order ID' textAlign='Right'></e-column>
            ...
     <e-column field='lastColumn' headerText='Actions' textAlign='Right'></e-column>
   </e-columns>
  <ng-template #rowTemplate let-data>
    <tr>
      <td>**//the checkbox needs to appear here**</td>
      <td>//html ui for order id</td>
       ...  
     <td>//html for last column</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
 </ejs-grid>
```

So, how can I add up checkbox in the custom <ng-template #rowTemlate> with its functionality of selection/deselection when the header checkbox is selected.